# vertically align textbox using bootstrap classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've made 5 rows using bootstrap, they got placed neatly, but there is a small issue. The rows are getting in contact without leaving any gap. I should not use 
, this will bring a big gap, and the textboxes in each row should be vertically align, if there is no radio button in that row, that corresponding place should be kept empty and textbox should get aligned properly with all rows. The starting textbox in all rows should start at the same place where the first row textbox has started. Here is my code

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="radio" style="width: 100px;">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option
                        1</label>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="radio" style="width: 100px;">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option
                        1</label>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel1">Select list:</label> <select
                        class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>Apple</option>
                        <option>Mango</option>
                        <option>Orange</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" /> <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="radio" style="width: 100px;">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option
                        1</label>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel1">Select list:</label> <select
                        class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>Apple</option>
                        <option>Mango</option>
                        <option>Orange</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" /> <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please check in browser not in fiddle because it changes alignments .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-inline form-group">
                <div class="radio" style="width:95px;" >
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" style="vertical-align:middle;"> &nbsp; Option
                        1</label>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-inline form-group">
                <div class="radio" style="width:95px;" >
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option
                        1</label>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel1">Select list:</label> <select
                        class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>Apple</option>
                        <option>Mango</option>
                        <option>Orange</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="form-inline form-group">
          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" /> <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-inline form-group">
                <div class="radio" style="width:95px;">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option
                        1</label>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel1">Select list:</label> <select
                        class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>Apple</option>
                        <option>Mango</option>
                        <option>Orange</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="form-inline form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" /> <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gomy6n5b/1/)

Comment: did you give class to `form-inline` div?

Comment: Yeah.. Just found and added.. Thanks Bhavin.. But hw can I put the textbox with the same position where firstbox has started.

Comment: can't you use `col-md-offset-n` , where n could be 1,2,3 , etc. to put the text box in same position.?

Comment: that should be added to which div?

Comment: to that div which you want your textbox to be in same position as per previous div.

Comment: Please find the url.. you can see the changes http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0WFPOZYUR1E

Comment: If you have any changes to the code with the best way with the alignment, plz let me know.. im new to this bootstrap ui

Comment: I have updated my answer. is this the same that you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128441/discussion-between-syed-and-bhavin-shah).

Comment: Got it Bhavin. :)